# How do I pull new employee information from DocuSign through API?

Tags: python, directory, active-directory, docusignapi

Is it possible to pull the new employee’s personal information who gets hired every day from DocuSign through API? I'm trying to find a way to automate the process of user account creation process from DocuSign to Active Directory by avoiding CSV file. New to this, any input might be useful?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this endeavor. 
The first, is not related to DocuSign. You need to get an event fired everytime a new contact is added to AD and be able to process this request. I assume you have a way to do that.

Then, the second part is using our REST API to add a new user.

Make a POST request to:

```
POST /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users
```

You pass this information in the request body:

```
{
  "newUsers": [
    {
      "userName": "Claire Horace",
      "email": "claire@example.com.com"
    },
    {
      "userName": "Tal Mason",
      "email": "tal@example.com.com",
      "userSettings": [
        {
          "name": "canSendEnvelope",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "locale",
          "value": "fr"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```